# Segmentation to one-hot encoding

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have a batch of segmented images of size

`seg` --> `[batch, channels, imsize, imgsize]` --> `[16, 6, 50, 50]`

each scalar in this tensor specifies one of the segmentation classes.
We have `2000` total segmentation classes.

Now the goal is to convert
`[16, 6, 50, 50]` --> `[16, 2000, 50, 50]`
where each class is encoded in one hot fashion.

How do I do it with pytorch api?
I can only think of ridiculously inefficient looping construction.

Example

Here we will have only 2 initial channels (instead of 6), 4 labels (instead of 2000), size batch 1 (instead of 16) and 4x4 image instead of 50x50.

```
0, 0, 1, 1
0, 0, 0, 1
1, 1, 1, 1
1, 1, 1, 1

3, 3, 2, 2
3, 3, 2, 2
3, 3, 2, 2
3, 3, 2, 2
```

Now this turns into 4 channel output

```
1, 1, 0, 0
1, 1, 1, 0
0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0

0, 0, 1, 1
0, 0, 0, 1
1, 1, 1, 1
1, 1, 1, 1

1, 1, 0, 0
1, 1, 0, 0
1, 1, 0, 0
1, 1, 0, 0

0, 0, 1, 1
0, 0, 1, 1
0, 0, 1, 1
0, 0, 1, 1
```

The key observation is that a particular label appears only on a single input channel.

Comment: What does the `6` represent? Your goal is to convert *16* *6*-channel *50x50* images into *16* *2000*-channel *50x50* images. You going from *15,000* points/image to *5,000,000* points/image. Are you sure this is what you're looking for?

Comment: @Ivan 6 is just some channels with labels from 0 to 2000. 
This is not that important detail... on channel 0 only subset of labels can be present , on channel 1 another subset of labels, etc. So channel zero partitions image on labels that correspond to objects, channel 1 partition image on labels that correspond to parts, etc. 
Now since there is 2000 total labels you owuld need 
2000 x imgsize x imgsize for one hot encoding. Does it make sense

Comment: Ok, on a given channel, say channel=0, how would you know which labels it corresponds to? I don't clearly see how would you go about converting a *6*-channel image into a *2000*-channel image of the same size.

Comment: @Ivan it would be given by a label number... 
Say channel zero has label 10 with some other labels.
Now [:, 10, :, :] would have 1 on the same location with 10 and 0 everywhere else. Does it make sense

Comment: I'm affraid I don't understand what you are describing. It would be a lot easier if you give an minimal example: take a 4x4 image with a few labels and show the desired result.

Comment: @Ivan sure, its done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this without too much trouble. Construct as many masks as there are labels, then stack those masks together, sum on the channel layer and convert to floats:

```
>>> x
tensor([[[0, 0, 1, 1],
         [0, 0, 0, 1],
         [1, 1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1, 1]],

        [[3, 3, 2, 2],
         [3, 3, 2, 2],
         [3, 3, 2, 2],
         [3, 3, 2, 2]]])

>>> y = torch.stack([x==i for i in range(x.max()+1)], dim=1).sum(dim=2)
tensor([[[1., 1., 0., 0.],
         [1., 1., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0., 1., 1.],
         [0., 0., 0., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1., 1.]],

        [[0., 0., 1., 1.],
         [0., 0., 1., 1.],
         [0., 0., 1., 1.],
         [0., 0., 1., 1.]],

        [[1., 1., 0., 0.],
         [1., 1., 0., 0.],
         [1., 1., 0., 0.],
         [1., 1., 0., 0.]]])
```

Comment: This is what I am getting
in 
torch.Size([16, 6, 50, 50])
out
torch.Size([2000, 6, 50, 50])

So something is off...

Comment: it's clearly not taking into account batch dimension , for the very least.

Comment: the other problem -- it still uses for loops instead of pytorch apis...which is way too slow if you work with large data

Comment: Should be fixed now, it was a matter of stacking/summing on the right axes. You have to realize this is not a straight forward task, you are trying to untangle an indeterminate number of labels from mutliple channels... you might not be able to achieve this only using tensors.